# Textbook/lab manual for mammalian cell culture

Tags: book-recommendation

For general techniques involving molecular biology, I know of [Sambrook and Maniatis Molecular Cloning](http://www.molecularcloning.com/) which covers many of the standard cloning techniques.

However, mammalian cell culture has many significant differences from bacterial cell culture, some of which include the [many different variants](http://www.protocol-online.org/biology-forums/posts/26803.html) of cell culture media as well as the relatively complex systems which cannot be provided using standardised media such as LB or TB in E. coli culture.

Are there any similar textbooks/lab manuals for cell culture? Alternatively, good review papers covering the different kinds of media used in mammalian cell culture and their relative benefits would also be a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Culture of Animal Cells: A Manual of Basic Technique and Specialized Applications*](http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470528125.html) by Ian Freshney is the most popular book on the topic of animal cell culture.

You can also refer to [ATCC animal cell culture guide](http://www.atcc.org/~/media/PDFs/Culture%20Guides/AnimCellCulture_Guide.ashx) which also has information about media formulations.