# how to culture mc38 cells

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture

I work at a start up company in a vivarium. My boss would like me to start working with MC38 Cells. I bought all of the equipment (recommended by a colleague) and should be ready for the cells. Could anyone recommend a good place to learn how to do this fast? He has surprised me and already ordered the cells. I do have some knowledge on the subject ( from bachelors degree in Biology), but it is not enough. I need somewhere that can teach me even the little steps. I have tried looking at scientific papers, but they typically skip over much of the steps that are common knowledge (to most).

Comment: actually, this question may be a duplicate of this question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36255/textbook-lab-manual-for-mammalian-cell-culture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textbook/lab manual for mammalian cell culture](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36255/textbook-lab-manual-for-mammalian-cell-culture)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: Similar questions have been asked before: [Textbook/lab manual for mammalian cell culture](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36255/textbook-lab-manual-for-mammalian-cell-culture)**

Cell culture reagent/consumables suppliers can have good step by step recommendations for how to use their products. For example [Thermo has some guidelines](https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/references/gibco-cell-culture-basics/cell-culture-protocols.html?gclid=CjwKCAjw26H3BRB2EiwAy32zhWgrbXZewEzaQJGzgGAhG9tMCfhJAzMJ0pvg_AY7IHReMQTGNY4plxoC05gQAvD_BwE&s_kwcid=AL!3652!3!342304045335!e!!g!!cell%20culture%20protocol&ef_id=CjwKCAjw26H3BRB2EiwAy32zhWgrbXZewEzaQJGzgGAhG9tMCfhJAzMJ0pvg_AY7IHReMQTGNY4plxoC05gQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!3652!3!342304045335!e!!g!!cell%20culture%20protocol&cid=bid_clb_cce_r01_co_cp0000_pjt0000_bid00000_0se_gaw_nt_awa_awa) that you may find helpful. Specifically, [cell culture maintenance](https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/references/gibco-cell-culture-basics/cell-culture-protocols/maintaining-cultured-cells.html) would seem to be helpful.

[These folks](https://www.ptglab.com/support/cell-culture-protocol/cell-culture-protocol/) also have what superficially look like good resources.

Reviewing [MC38 culture requirements](https://www.kerafast.com/productgroup/665/mc-38-cell-line) is also always a good idea.

Good luck!